# Magento 2 - Custom page layout not working properly

Tags: magento2, product, layout, catalog, page-layouts

I have some big grouped products (with sku: montagekonsole and montageschiene). I need to change the layout for both.

First I just created custom sku handles for each product like this:

#### THEME/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_sku_montagekonsole.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" 
                   htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container">
            <!-- Page Builder Row -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                   name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" template="Company_Base::page-builder/row/contained.phtml" />
        </container>
        
        <move element="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" 
              destination="page.wrapper" before="hf_product_details_tabs_container" />
        
        <move element="product.info" 
              destination="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This works perfectly fine.

But since I don't want to duplicate the exact same file again and again for any product where I need to apply this, I created a new page layout:

---

#### THEME\Magento_Theme\layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="hf-grouped-product-big-1col">
        <label translate="true">Hf Grouped Product (Big) -- 1 Col</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

#### THEME\Magento_Theme\page_layout\hf-grouped-product-big-1col.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>

    <container name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" 
               htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container">
        <!-- Page Builder Row -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
               name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" 
               template="Company_Base::page-builder/row/contained.phtml" />
    </container>

    <move element="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" 
          destination="page.wrapper" before="hf_product_details_tabs_container" />

    <move element="product.info" 
          destination="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" after="-" />
</layout>
```

Then I deleted the now not needed layout `THEME/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_sku_montagekonsole.xml` again and changed the page layout in the product with the sku `montagekonsole` to my new Page Layout **Hf Grouped Product (Big) -- 1 Col** and flushed the cache.

But now the container `hf_big_grouped_product_table_container` is loaded at the very bottom after the footer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what was the layout previously selected for your product (when you used the first layout update file for that particular sku)?

Comment: It was set to "No Layout updates"

Comment: do you think you could rollback and add the initial approach and select '1column' then check if the issue still occurs? i have a hunch, but i am not sure if it's what i'm thinking of.

Comment: I already tried that. But I tested it again (applying the THEME/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_sku_montagekonsole.xml again and setting Layout Update to `1 column`) . It works this way.

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll think of something else then :)

Comment: is your theme inheriting another theme? if so, which one?

Comment: Yes, my theme inherits from the Luma Theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123232/discussion-between-diana-botean-and-black).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new page layout should look like this (note that I am referencing the `page.wrapper` and adding the custom container and block inside as opposed to adding the custom container then moving it as displayed in your trial code):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
         <container name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container">
            <!-- Page Builder Row -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                  name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" 
                  template="Company_Base::page-builder/row/contained.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <move element="product.info" destination="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" after="-" />
</layout>
```

However, as discussed in the chat there are issues with regards to the referenced block `hf_product_details_tabs_container` which is defined somewhere else, so I have omitted the 'before' instructions above.

Since this looks like a business specific issue, I would suggest you take the example of the `Page_Builder` module which defines a new layout `product-full-width.xml` on top of `1column` layout and start from there, maybe you need to redefine the page structure in order to accommodate your custom 'hf_product_details_tabs_container' block so that the 'hf_big_grouped_product_table_block' is rendered in the proper location.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thx for your assistance. The problem is that my custom **page layout** is loaded **before** the layout `catalog_product_view.xml` where `hf_product_details_tabs_container` is defined. So the `catalog_product_view.xml` is overwriting the changes from my custom page layout.

I need to force my page layout to get loaded last somehow. I think I will need to extend some core class to achieve this. I will try this. +1 for your assistance!

Comment: no problem, anytime! hope you sort this out soon!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is in the nature of the layouts `<move>` statements in general.

All layout files are getting merged to one big layout file at the end.

The page layouts are getting loaded earlier than other layouts, so they are getting overriden by layouts which are getting loaded later.

---

I had defined the container **hf_product_details_tabs_container** in the following layout file and moved it to the container "main.content" by using the move statement.

### THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        ...
        
        <move element="hf_product_details_tabs_container" destination="page.wrapper" after="main.content" />

        ...

        <container name="hf_product_details_tabs_container" 
                       htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_product_details_tabs_container"/>

        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

#### Problem:

I had to change my **catalog_product_view.xml** to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="hf_product_details_tabs_container" 
                       htmlTag="div"
                       htmlId="hf_product_details_tabs_container"
                       after="main.content"
            />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and I had to change the page_layout to this, like @Diana Botean pointed out correctly:

### THEME\Magento_Theme\page_layout\hf-grouped-product-big-1col.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
         <container name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container"
                    htmlTag="div" 
                    htmlId="hf_big_grouped_product_table_container" 
                    before="hf_product_details_tabs_container"
         >
            <!-- Page Builder Row -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                  name="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" 
                  template="Company_Base::page-builder/row/contained.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <move element="product.info" destination="hf_big_grouped_product_table_block" after="-" />
</layout>
```

I will add more information about this, as soon as I gained more knowledge about the move statements.